# A model structure on CDGAs

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, model-categories

Assume our base ring $k=\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ or $\mathbb{F}_p$ and
for simplicity
let us consider non-negative-graded connected algebras $A$ with an augmentation, i.e. $A^0=k,A^{<0}=0$.

The question: Is there are any model structure on the category of cdga's with weak equivalences are quasi-isomorphisms?

It is known that the right transferring by the adjunction (Free,Forget) from complexes to cdga
does not provide a model structure: weak equivalence of cofibrant complexes
$0\to (x,dx)$ with even $x$, maps to a non-acyclic morphism $0\to P(x,dx)$.
The Dold-Kan correspondence with simplicial commutative
algebras is not possible, since the adjoint to normalization functor $N$ takes values
in non-commutative simplicial algebras.
The Quillen construction from rational homotopy theory, instead,
regards $N$ as a right adjoint, but requires $k\supset\mathbb{Q}$.

Assume a model structure exists.
One can check that there is no non-trivial map $f:E\to P$ from an acyclic cdga $E$
to the polynomial algebra $P$ on even variables.
In short, such map requires divided powers in $P$:
if $f(\tilde{x})=x$, then $d\tilde{y}=\tilde{x}^{p-1}d\tilde{x}$ for some $\tilde{y}\in E$,
hence $f(p\tilde{y}-\tilde{x}^p)$ is exact, hence it is zero and $p$ divides $x^p$.

In particular (w.e.+cof,fib)-factorization $k\to E\to P$ produces a fibration
$E\to P$ which is an augmentation $E\to k\to P$. The LLP for $k\to P$ reduces to LLP of
$E\to P$, hence the inclusion $k\to P$ is also fibration. It seems to be pathological, but I'm unable come to
condradiction.

Comment: Presumably you only want to consider model structures for which the weak equivalences are the quasiisomorphisms; perhaps you should say that.  (There are certainly model structures for which the weak equivalences are the isomorphisms.)

Comment: @NeilStrickland, sure! and I want to add, that there are less trivial examples: I expect we can realize the right transferring from complexes by applying divided powers functor, then taking its right adjoint induces a class of weak equivalences other that quasi-isomorphisms. In this case $k\to P(x)$ becomes a fibration.

Comment: Maybe this paper answers your question?  https://hopf.math.purdue.edu//Stanley/stanley1.pdf

Comment: @theL, thanks for pointing this work, it seems to answer my question, but not claryfies! As far as I understand, some "small object argument" is used there to establish a naive answer: taking relative Sullivan algebras for cofibrations determines a model structure for any base ring. Does this construction provide a (co)fibrant replacement, path objects etc.? can we apply this result to compute at least anything in Ho(cdga's)?

Comment: @BadEnglish, I seem to remember writing to Donald Stanley about this a few years ago, and if I remember correctly, he said that this model structure does have a cofibrant replacement functor.